# Jquery ajax form post to Laravel 4Bt

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an Ajax post to my laravel backend. I serialize the form and sent it but I am not sure how I can use a proper Format in my laravel backend(php):

My Ajax:

```
submitPdf: function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {

        if($("#pdfPreviewCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        var $form = $(this);

        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/test/public/labelspecial/new/input",
            data: {
                "product": serializedData
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("an error occured " + e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

if I `var_dump(Input::all());` I get an output like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["product"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(11) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["model"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    array(11) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["model"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=>
    array(11) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["model"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["printPDF"]=>
  string(6) "Senden"
  ["variant"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["count"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "T7aAxjnfAyAcGs5PAW75RBbEFjfYpt4eCgO7iT1j"
}
```

And if I sent the serialized data via Ajax I get this Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["product"]=>
  string(1135) "product%5B0%5D%5Blabel%5D=&product%5B0%5D%5Bmodel%5D=&product%5B0%5D%5B...
}
```

The Output Needs to be the same how can I accomplish that?

Edit I tried to use `$form.serializedArray()` instead of `$form.serialize()`, I get a better result but it is not correct yet. If I `dd` in php I get this now:

```
array(1) {
  ["product"]=>
  string(1626) "[{"name":"product[0][label]","value":""}]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form-object to fetch all inputs within the form.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {

        if($("#pdfPreviewCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            return true;
        }

            var form = $( this );

            // you can't pass Jquery form it has to be javascript form object
            var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

  $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "someURl",
            data: {
                 formData 
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("an error occured " + e);
            }
        });
    });
```

Laravel Controller:

```
public function methodName(Request $request){
return $request->all();
}
```

If you want to access only specified input then you can use like below

```
return $request->inputName;
```

Route :

```
Route::post("/someURl", ControllerName@methodName);
```